# Different code behavior using VSC Debugger (out of bounds on iterable)

Tags: python, pytorch, multiprocessing, pickle, vscode-debugger

I have an iterable with appropriate **len** and **getitem** methods implemented.

I pickle this object to a "train_file.pth" pickle file.

Then, when running the following code snippet :

```
with open(train_file_name, "rb") as file:
     train_objects = pickle.load(file)

for object in train_objects :
     object.set_variable(some_value, 0)
     object.set_variable(some_other_value, 1)
```

## **WITHOUT DEBUGGER**

Every call to the set_variable methods works

## **WITH DEBUGGER**

I get the following error when iterating :

```
list index out of range
  File "C:\some_dir\my_file.py", line 225, in __getitem__
    return self._objects[k]
  File "C:\some_dir\my_other_file.py", line 236, in <module>
    for object in train_objects:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

And I have trouble to undestand what is going on in here. Why does using the debugger makes my code bug, and where does that "index out of range" error comes from? This is not even when accessing a specific item, but when using the built-in **iter** method...

I checked for the iterable methods definition, and as it works without debugger, I do not see any lead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common behavior of the VSC Debugger, that I always recommend to never use. Basically, this tool wraps many different calls to a lot of libraries I will not go into further details here.

To sum up, change your IDE to PyCharm, which is much more reliable and efficient as compared to VSC, for many reasons I will not detail here. You can find resources [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles), detailing many of the ""amazing"" ideas they have.

If you want to understand this error, it is due to handling of pickle files by the VSC Debugger, that reinitialises the methods contained in an iterable object - per se, it is not terrible in itself. For some specific cases like yours, it is a dreadful error.

Comment: Eclipse debugger in a PyDev project is also a useful tool.

Comment: It seems a bit extreme of a solution, isn't there a simpler alternative? I would at least like to understand what is going on...

Comment: If this is a common problem, do you have a reference to other Stack Overflow issues that this one might duplicate?